# Strange background rendering on chrome while background-attachment:fixed;

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background, fixed

I wanted my background to be fixed, I did this a lot of times but this time when I scroll it gets distorted with no reason, I managed to make navigation bar not distorted not adding

```
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

to it but I don't how to fix the background. It only happens on Chrome, works fine with IE.
http://imgur.com/pANZViI

Here's the demo:
http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/

Here's the css:

```
background:url(images/background.jpg) #ff7400 no-repeat left top;
background-size: 100%;
background-attachment:fixed;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, the demo looks the same on FF and chrome

Comment: Really? Have you checked screenshot on imgur? It looks the same on multiply computers.

Comment: You should attach an image of it not working and an image of it working so we can see what's the correct behaviour that you are looking for

Comment: I can reproduce his problem instantly in Chrome; the background does not stay fixed, it gets distorted when scrolling up/down. Adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the body fixes the background, but then the nav can't stay fixed anymore...

Comment: yeah, looks like I'm gonna have to deal with it lol..

Comment: One sec...I see your issue I think...where's that black gif background? On what DIV...can't find it

Comment: Nm..found it. Bad coding btw...but let me look.

Comment: Got it..I'll post answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start...clean up this CSS and use:

```
body {
   background: url(images/background.jpg) #ff7400 no-repeat left top;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Then change the `z-index` to this. It shouldn't be negative -1. That was your problem:

```
#animacja {
   position: fixed;
   top: 200px;
   right: -70px;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

And fix/add `z-index` on your menu bar so it's above that graphic:

```
#mainMenu {
   position: relative;
   height: 80px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: fixed;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: No prob. Easy peezy! Chrome Developer tools is your friend. :)